# How to remove menu and submenu items in WordPress backend

Tags: wordpress

I need to hide / remove a menu and submenu in WordPress backend.

Main menu item:

```
admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard
```

Sub menu items:

```
admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard&tab=builder
admin.php?page=_options&tab=1
admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard&tab=license
```

I have tried the code below code, but that does not work. Two of the subpages link to the same page but show different tabs.

```
function remove_menus(){
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard' );                                                         //themeit
        remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard', 'admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard&tab=builder' );      //themeit
        remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=_options', 'admin.php?page=_options&tab=1' );                              //themeit
        remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard', 'admin.php?page=themeit_dashboard&tab=license' );      //themeit
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Comment: Could you just hide via css? If that would work for you, you could add a editor-style.css to your theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style), find the id or class of the menus/submenus you want to hide, and remove via display:none.

Comment: Will it be possible to it with CSS and have different menus on each user role (admin, editor etc.). @scmccarthy22

Comment: try adding third arg priority like `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 99 );`

Comment: @ShravanSharma Unfortunately that does not help. I am almost certain that I am making a mistake regarding the remove_submenu_page. ('admin.php?page=_options', 'admin.php?page=_options&tab=1').

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using current_user_can() and remove_menu_page, as you tried to do.

But It can be done by without coding too.... long back I was using a plugin called - "Advanced Access Manager". Use that or any similar plugins.

With those you will be able to assign permisson on menus based on roles with a cool UI.

I personally did found it very easy.

Answer (score 0):

set **null** ($parent_slug) the first parameter in add_submenu_page for hide submenu items.

```
add_submenu_page (
    null, 
    'Admin Post',
    'Admin Post',
    'manage_options',
    'admin-post',
    'admin_post_page' 
)
```

if you do not understand, you can watch the video: https://youtu.be/TGVGgbQ-GNs